# How to find_all(data-video-id) from html using beautiful soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

How can I get the `data-video-id` attribute from the below HTML using `BeautifulSoup`?

```
<a href="/watch/36242552" class="thumbnail video vod-show play-video-trigger user-can-watch" data-video-id="36242552" data-video-type="show">
```

The following prints an empty `list`.

```
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
ids = [tag['data-video-id'] for tag in soup.select('a href[data-video-id]')]
print(ids)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty `[]` because `soup.select('a href[data-video-id]')` is return nothing.You could try below code. Hope its help you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<a href="/watch/36242552" class="thumbnail video vod-show play-video-trigger user-can-watch" data-video-id="36242552" data-video-type="show">"""

# html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print(soup.select('a href[data-video-id]'))
ids = [tag['data-video-id'] for tag in soup.select('a') if tag['data-video-id']]
print(ids)
```